# PayPal "Buy Now" button doesn't work in production mode

Tags: button, paypal, production

I'm using "buy now" PayPal button. It works perfectly in testing mode ("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"), but in production mode ("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr") it doesn't work at all. When I click on the button, the following message from PayPal server appears: "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."
Could you please explain me what is wrong.

Comment: in which platform you are implementing the paypal

Comment: self-developed, if I correctly understood your question

Comment: I mean on which technology. i.e on php , android etc.

Comment: on php technology

Comment: The problem was not in scripts, but in my PayPal account, which worked not properly. Now everything OK. Thanks everybody!

Comment: What was the source of your problem?  My website suddenly started giving this error when the buyer is transferred to PayPal to submit payment.  I cannot figure out what has precipitated this new behaviour.

Comment: I forgot to fill out one mandatory worksheet, therefore PayPal limited the functionality of my account.